# How do you get a timestamp in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

How can I get a timestamp in ClojureScript, similar to Unix's timestamp, a single number that represents the current time and date, as a number. I know that:

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
}
```

can be used in Javascript but I want to know if there is a ClojureScript equivalant

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use

```
(.getTime (js/Date.))
```

or you could also use `now` or `epoch` from [cljs-time](https://github.com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time).

Answer (score 9):

The most efficient way is this

```
(.now js/Date)
```

Other answers needlessly create a Date object.